# Does the pwm pin on an lmd18200 have to be connected to a pwm pin?

Tags: arduino, pwm, h-bridge

I got an lmd18200 connected to an Arduino Uno. The pwm pin is connected to the 10 pin on the Arduino. Will this not work?

Comment: Of course it will work. How exactly is an open question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally (LMD18200 - pin 5 is PWM input), from the microcontroller side (arduino) you can use any PWM capability pins (make sure your selected pin is generating PWM perfectly. if your Arduino output the PWM then LMD18200 should work otherwise you may have problem PWM signal.